# How to use Cloud9 with Java and Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku, github, cloud9-ide

I'm currently experimenting with the idea of having a full cloud development environment. I decided to go with Cloud9 IDE and deploy my app on Heroku while using GitHub to store my code. As Java is my most comfortable language, I'm adopting it for my app.

Now the Heroku tutorials use Maven for Java packaging. Is there any way I can replicate this in Cloud9, or can I skip the Maven altogether? Or must I manually put in all the pom files myself?

Note: I do intend to install Toolbelt on my local machine, but there will be times when I want to do coding when I'm not at home and don't have access to the local server. I'm more interested in knowing if it is possible to not have any dependence on a local machine at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment as Cloud9 lacks build tools for Java. A thing called 'private RunVMs' will be launched in the next couple of weeks that allow you to install a Java build environment from within Cloud9; then deploying to Heroku would be possible for Java apps as well. Keep an eye on [the blog](http://c9.io/site/blog) for updates.

**edit** Cloud9 now has private VMs. It should be possible to install a java runtime in Cloud9 if you are on a premium plan now.

Comment: I see! In that case, could I build my project locally using Maven, then upload it to Github, and then not rely on Maven any more? Or will I need to keep rebuilding it each time I want to deploy? Is there any manual workaround at the moment?

Comment: No workaround at the moment for Cloud9 hosted. You can install Cloud9 Open Source on an Amazon EC2 server (or any VPS really) and use an online SSH service to log into there and kick off deployments. (Or have some patience, we'll release in a couple of weeks :-))